# -esttab- dropping time dummies

Tags: compare, export, output, regression

I am trying to export my regression results by Stata to Excel.

```
xtreg index_bhar adsue1 i.date, fe cluster(company_id) dfadj
estimates store FTFE1,title("Stock FTFE DSUE1")

xtreg index_bhar adsue2 i.date, fe cluster(company_id) dfadj
estimates store FTFE2,title("Stock FTFE DSUE2")

xtreg index_bhar adsue3 i.date, fe cluster(company_id) dfadj
estimates store FTFE3,title("Stock FTFE DSUE3")

esttab using BHAR_regression_csv.csv, cells(b(star fmt(%9.5f)) se(par fmt(%9.5f))) drop(_Idate*) stats(N ar2)
```

The last step does not work, no matter "how" I drop the `i.date` variable. I tried:

```
_Idate*

*date*

i.date

*_date_*
```

Moreover, I would like to add text (like in `outreg2` (http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Outreg2.pdf) because I am going to compare FE vs RE vs OLS.

### Edit

I run

```
xtreg  index_bhar adsue3 i.date, fe cluster(company_id) dfadj
matrix list r(table)
which esttab
```

and get the following result:

```
r(table)[9,37]
                          177b.        178.        179.        180.        181.        182.        183.        184.        185.        186.
            adsue3        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date
     b   .06636876           0  -.00551558  -.01558847  -.01223474  -.02825648  -.01797169  -.02353377  -.02351679  -.03266691   -.0270249
    se   .00547756           .   .00742083   .00708063   .00731967    .0070688    .0064812   .00733153   .00801699   .00725142   .00718932
     t   12.116494           .    -.743256  -2.2015648  -1.6714891  -3.9973525  -2.7728929  -3.2099395  -2.9333704  -4.5048967  -3.7590343
pvalue   2.123e-29           .   .45771891    .0282086   .09532812   .00007497   .00578939   .00142372   .00352624   8.497e-06   .00019331
    ll   .05560367           .  -.02009981   -.0295041  -.02662015  -.04214886  -.03070926   -.0379425  -.03927265  -.04691819  -.04115414
    ul   .07713385           .   .00906865  -.00167284   .00215067  -.01436411  -.00523411  -.00912505  -.00776093  -.01841562  -.01289566
    df         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445
  crit   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092
 eform           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0

               187.        188.        189.        190.        191.        192.        193.        194.        195.        196.        197.
              date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date
     b  -.01494385  -.04620886   -.0555639  -.03572873  -.02022551  -.04343248  -.02897542   .00823335   .00360491  -.03832982   .01898826
    se   .00767353   .00702574   .00719699   .00910337   .00841343   .00953967   .01449665   .01373734   .01801534   .00976289   .01180829
     t  -1.9474554  -6.5770847  -7.7204359  -3.9247818   -2.403956  -4.5528285  -1.9987665   .59934072   .20010199  -3.9260751   1.6080448
pvalue   .05210873   1.349e-10   7.722e-14   .00010055   .01662665   6.841e-06   .04624143   .54925071   .84149223   .00010003   .10853459
    ll  -.03002471   -.0600166  -.06970821  -.05361967   -.0367605  -.06218089  -.05746582  -.01876477  -.03180081  -.05751691  -.00421868
    ul     .000137  -.03240112  -.04141959   -.0178378  -.00369052  -.02468408  -.00048502   .03523146   .03901062  -.01914273   .04219519
    df         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445
  crit   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092
 eform           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0

               198.        199.        200.        201.        202.        203.        204.        205.        206.        207.        208.
              date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date        date
     b  -.00349209   .01009475  -.05471275  -.02974371  -.02135717  -.02611022  -.03897832  -.05436064  -.01511528  -.04263671  -.03508992
    se   .00784112   .01076697   .00854308   .00684135   .00770194   .00762225   .00711017   .01004461   .00849691   .00786062   .00874839
     t  -.44535604   .93756631  -6.4043313  -4.3476349  -2.7729599  -3.4255286  -5.4820548  -5.4119214  -1.7789158  -5.4240873  -4.0110133
pvalue   .65627905   .34897589   3.845e-10   .00001707   .00578822   .00067052   7.057e-08   1.021e-07   .07593611   9.579e-08   .00007091
    ll  -.01890232  -.01106568  -.07150255  -.04318909  -.03649387  -.04109029  -.05295199   -.0741014  -.03181434  -.05808527  -.05228321
    ul   .01191814   .03125518  -.03792294  -.01629833  -.00622048  -.01113015  -.02500464  -.03461988   .00158377  -.02718815  -.01789662
    df         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445         445
  crit   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092
 eform           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0

               209.        210.        211.            
              date        date        date       _cons
     b   -.0238768  -.00742588  -.02083166  -.00432197
    se   .00831877   .00967837    .0094757   .00546817
     t  -2.8702321  -.76726574   -2.198429  -.79038681
pvalue   .00429722   .44333042   .02843267    .4297229
    ll  -.04022575  -.02644688  -.03945434  -.01506861
    ul  -.00752784   .01159511  -.00220897   .00642467
    df         445         445         445         445
  crit   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092   1.9653092
 eform           0           0           0           0

. which esttab
c:\ado\plus\e\esttab.ado
*! version 2.0.6  02jun2014  Ben Jann
*! wrapper for estout
```

I am using Stata/SE 12.0.

I have run the code but the result is the same, Stata cannot find the coefficient *.date.

Comment: You should update Stata to 12.1. Run `update all`. Then try running the code I posted under **Edit 2** in my answer, and report back. I don't see why the `drop()` option shouldn't work. Your `<num>.date` variables are there as `matrix list r(table)` shows.

Comment: Did previous advice work for you?

Comment: Dear Roberto, with the example data from you it works perfectly but I could not make it work with my own data, but with -outreg2- I could drop it (just with drop(i.date)). Therefore, I guess there is a problem in the data(?). Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I couldn't say where your problem lies without more information. If you can, I suggest you post a minimal working example that reproduces the error (includes some data points, and code that is giving problem) so we have a better chance of discovering the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify your exact error. Presumably:

> coefficient  not found
>
> r(111);

but I can't really understand what you say you've tried.

With factor notation virtual variables are created that have the following form: `num.varname`, so `drop`ping `*.varname` is enough. A nonsensical example:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto

*----- what you want -----

eststo clear

eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg
        
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg i.foreign

esttab, ar2 title(Model Comparison for Price) ///
    mtitles("first model" "second model") drop(*.foreign)
```

I'm not able to open the link you give, but consider using the `title()` and `mtitles()` options to introduce text in the table (also exemplified). Add `using ...` to export to `.csv`.

### Edit

One issue with your code is that you're not using `eststo` to store your results, but rather `estimates store`. This is valid, but then you have to explicitly list the names of the stored results when you call `esttab`. If you don't, then `esttab` will use only the results of the model that was last fit (whether they were saved or not using `estimates store`). For example, this works as expected:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto

*----- what you want -----

estimates clear

quietly regress price weight mpg
estimates store first
       
quietly regress price weight mpg i.foreign
estimates store second

esttab first second, ar2 title(Model Comparison for Price) ///
    mtitles("first model" "second model") drop(*.foreign)
```

The implication then, is that your code uses only the last available result:

```
xtreg index_bhar adsue3 i.date, fe cluster(company_id) dfadj
```

But here, I suspect the option `drop(*.date)` should work.

### Edit 2

Try running this and report back exact results in your original post:

```
xtreg index_bhar adsue3 i.date, fe cluster(company_id) dfadj 

matrix list r(table)

esttab, ar2 title(Model Comparison) ///
    mtitles("first model") drop(*.date)
```

Comment: dear Roberto, the mistake is exactly what you´ve described. I googled and saw different ways to address dummy variables, that´s what I meant with "tried". I tried to use     drop(*.date) but this does not work either.  Is it because I stored my models differently?

Comment: I've added some information to my answer. Add `matrix list r(table)` one line below `xtreg ...`. Show us _exactly_ what you get after you run your code; copy/paste from the Stata results window into your original post. Use the _edit_ button provided in your original post to introduce this information. Post also the version of Stata you're using (run `about`). Post the version of `esttab` you're using (run `which esttab`).